# Rails - bundle error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundle

I created a new project, run all basic commands and everything worked fine. But now I tried to add some gems and when I run bundle, I get the error:

```
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in `to_specs': Could not find bundler (>= 0) amongst [bundler-unload-1.0.2, did_you_mean-1.0.0, executable-hooks-1.3.2, gem-wrappers-1.2.7, minitest-5.8.3, net-telnet-0.1.1, power_assert-0.2.6, rake-10.4.2, rubygems-bundler-1.4.4, rvm-1.11.3.9, test-unit-3.1.5] (Gem::LoadError)
```

I'm using ruby 2.3.1 on that project (checked on rvm list), so I think it's wrong that it try to run on `/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/`

Anybody know the reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you have bundler installed.

Run `gem install bundler`

Comment: It gives me an error:

An error occurred while installing nio4r (1.2.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install nio4r -v '1.2.1'` succeeds before bundling.

Then, if try that command, comes another error. If I use ruby 2.2.2 version, it works fine, but I wanna use 2.3.1. And I have it installed on rvm. But on /usr/lib/ruby, there's no folder for it there